# Cannot connect to the real github.com in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, github

Recently, when i use Chrome to visit github, i meet the following error.

**Cannot connect to the real github.com**
Something is currently interfering with your secure connection to github.

**Try to reload this page in a few minutes or after switching to a new network.** If you have recently connected to a new Wi-Fi network, finish logging in before reloading.

If you were to visit githu.com right now, you might share private information with an attacker. To protect your privacy, Chrome will not load the page until it can establish a secure connection to the real github.com.

It works well in Firefox/Safari, my desktop environment is Mac OS Mavericks, 
anybody can help on it?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question doesn't appear to a programming problem, so it doesn't seem to be on topic here.  However, there are a number of sister sites, one of which might be appropriate to your question.

Comment: I'm getting the same exact issue in both Chrome and Canary, but not Safari.

Comment: I just consult the Github Staff, They said one of their SSL certificates providers was having some issues, and give me the solution for Mac OS: 1. open Keychain Access app 2. select View menu and select "Show Expired Certificates" 3. delete the expired certificates in the list and restart browsers. i followed the steps and it works now

Comment: ^ The above worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to delete the expired certificate from your login keychain, and restart Chrome.

Here is the DigiCert link that explains how to do it.

https://blog.digicert.com/expired-intermediate-certificate/

> On July 26,2014 at 12:15 PM, some customers and users on sites secured by DigiCert reported that Mac OS X systems were experiencing certificate chain errors due to what appears to be a bug in how the Apple OS handles expired intermediate certificates in the SSL trust chain. Customers on Windows and other platforms have not reported any issues.
>   The problem actually affect any client platform with a locally cached intermediate certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have resolved this issue with Github Staff. the solution is similar with yours.